# How to find and correct skew using leptonica library in android tesseract tool

Tags: android, tesseract, skew

I am implementing android image processing. In that i have sample image,from that image i want to detect skew of image![my sample image have skew . i want to correct that result image should be unskew respect to number plate(number plate become in straight line after skew apply]. So i can send that area to tesseract OCR and return number plate number
Note:solution should not be in OpencV

Answer (score 0):

Leptonica has a slew of [deskew](http://tpgit.github.io/Leptonica/skew_8c.html) functions. I'm not sure if the Android binding exposes them, though.